# What is $\tan(\alpha+2\beta)\tan(2\alpha+\beta)$, if $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = 1$ and $\sin(\alpha-\beta) = \frac 12$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = 1$, $\sin(\alpha-\beta) = \frac 12$ , where $\alpha$, $\beta$ belongs to $[0,\frac \pi2],$ then what is $\tan(\alpha+2\beta)\tan(2\alpha+\beta)$?

What should be my approach to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of a different approach -

We can make an observation first.
If sin($\alpha$+$\beta$) = 1, then cos($\alpha$+$\beta$)=0; no matter what values $\alpha$ and $\beta$ take. Now, let me replace "$\alpha$+$\beta$" by another variable say "$A$". So, we have cos$A$ = 0. Therefore -

cos$3A$ = 4cos$^3A$ - 3cos$A$ = 4(0) - 3(0) = 0.

Thus, cos$3A$ = 0 = cos($3\alpha$+$3\beta$) ............ (1)

Now, writing our expression -

tan($\alpha$+$2\beta$)tan($2\alpha$+$\beta$)

= $\frac{2sin(\alpha+2\beta)sin(2\alpha+\beta)}{2cos(\alpha+2\beta)cos(2\alpha+\beta)}$

=$\frac{cos(\alpha-\beta) - cos(3\alpha+3\beta)}{cos(3\alpha+3\beta) + cos(\alpha-\beta)}$

=$\frac{cos(\alpha-\beta) - 0}{0 + cos(\alpha-\beta)}$   (from equation 1)

= 1

Comment: For trigonometric identities, you may refer this: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html

Also, this suggests that the range of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ might not be necessarily needed...

Answer (score 2):

Where does $\sin{x} = 1?$ In this case, $x = \pi/2.$  Where does $\sin{x} = 1/2?$ At $x = \pi/6$ in this case.  This gives you your system,
$$ \alpha+ \beta = \pi/2; \;\;\; \alpha - \beta = \pi/6.$$
From here, one can solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and then plug in to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, knowing what angles in the domain $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ give you $\sin(\cdot)=1$ and $\sin(\cdot)=\frac{1}{2}$, we can say that 
$$
\alpha + \beta = \pi/2
$$
and 
$$
\alpha - \beta = \pi/6
$$
This is a system of two equations with two unknowns.  After you know $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you can plug in.

Answer (score 2):

Since

\begin{align}
0\leq \alpha \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~0\leq \beta \leq \frac{\pi}{2},
\end{align}

we have

\begin{align}
0\leq \alpha+\beta \leq \pi,~~~~~~~~~~~~-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \alpha-\beta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}

Thus, from the equations given, we find that

\begin{align}
\sin(\alpha+\beta)&=1\Rightarrow \alpha+\beta=\frac{\pi}{2},\\
\sin(\alpha-\beta)&=1/2\Rightarrow \alpha-\beta=\frac{\pi}{6}.
\end{align}

Solving, we get $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\beta=\frac{\pi}{6}$. Thus,

\begin{align}
\tan(2\alpha+\beta)\tan(\alpha+2\beta)=\left(-\sqrt{3}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Directly calculate values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Since the angles lie in $[0; \dfrac{\pi}2]$, we get $\alpha+\beta=\dfrac{\pi}2$ and $\alpha-\beta=\dfrac{\pi}6$. Solve the system of linear equations and substitute into product of tangents. Can you proceed it from here?